# How do I code this dependently-typed example in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, gadt, dependent-type

Suppose I want to represent the finite models of the first-order language with constant c, unary function symbol f, and predicate P.  I can represent the carrier as a list `m`, the constant as an element of `m`, the function as a list of ordered pairs of elements of `m` (which can be applied via a helper function `ap`), and the predicate as a list of the elements of `m` that satisfy it:

```
-- Models (m, c, f, p) with element type a
type Model a = ([a], a, [(a,a)], [a])

-- helper function application, assumes function is total
ap :: Eq a => [(a,b)] -> a -> b
ap ((x',y'):ps) x = if x == x' then y' else ap ps x
```

I can then construct particular models and operations on models.  The details aren't important for my question, just the types (but I've included the definitions so you can see where the type constraints come from):

```
unitModel :: Model ()
unitModel = ([()], (), [((),())], [])

cyclicModel :: Int -> Model Int
cyclicModel n | n > 0 = ([0..n-1], 0, [(i, (i+1)`mod`n) | i<-[0..n-1]], [0])

-- cartesian product of models
productModel :: (Eq a, Eq b) => Model a -> Model b -> Model (a,b)
productModel (m1, c1, f1, p1) (m2, c2, f2, p2) = (m12, c12, f12, p12) where
  m12 = [(x1,x2) | x1 <- m1, x2 <- m2]
  c12 = (c1, c2)
  f12 = [(x12, (ap f1 (fst x12), ap f2 (snd x12))) | x12 <- m12]
  p12 = [x12 | x12 <- m12, elem (fst x12) p1 && elem (snd x12) p2]

-- powerset of model (using operations from Data.List)
powerModel :: (Eq a, Ord a) => Model a -> Model [a]
powerModel (m, c, f, p) = (ms, cs, fs, ps) where
  ms = subsequences (sort m) -- all subsets are "normalized"
  cs = [c]
  fs = [(xs, nub (sort (map (ap f) xs))) | xs <- ms] -- "renormalize" the image of f
  ps = [xs | xs <- ms, elem c xs]
```

Now, I want to give names to all of these models:

```
data ModelName = UnitModel
               | CyclicModel Int
               | Product ModelName ModelName
               | Power ModelName
               deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Finally, I want to write this code, mapping each name to the model it names:

```
model_of UnitModel = unitModel
model_of (CycleModel n) = cycleModel n
model_of (Product m1 m2) = productModel (model_of m1) (model_of m2)
model_of (Power m1) = powerModel (model_of m1)
```

I've tried a number of approaches to making this to work, in the sense of defining types so that I can use exactly this definition of model_of, including using phantom types, GADTs, and type families -- but haven't found a way to do it.  (But then again, I'm a relative newcomer to Haskell.)  Can it be done?  How should I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By using a GADT for `ModelName` you can associate a given name with the resulting model's type parameter. Here's what's needed to make your `model_of` compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data ModelName t where
    UnitModel   :: ModelName ()
    CyclicModel :: Int -> ModelName Int
    Product     :: (Eq a, Eq b) => ModelName a -> ModelName b -> ModelName (a, b)
    Power       :: (Ord a) => ModelName a -> ModelName [a]

model_of :: ModelName t -> Model t
model_of UnitModel       = unitModel
model_of (CyclicModel n) = cyclicModel n
model_of (Product m1 m2) = productModel (model_of m1) (model_of m2)
model_of (Power m1)      = powerModel (model_of m1)
```

EDIT: as you noticed, the normal `deriving` clause doesn't work with GADTs but it turns out `StandaloneDeriving` works just fine.

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

deriving instance Show (ModelName t)
deriving instance Eq (ModelName t)
```

Note, however, that the `Eq` instance is a bit nonsensical in this case because the type-class allows you to only compare values of the same type, but the different constructors essentially produce values of different types. So, for example, the following does not even type-check:

```
UnitModel == CyclicModel
```

because `UnitModel` and `CyclicModel` have different types (`ModelName ()` and `ModelName Int` respectively). For situations where you need to erase the additional type-information for some reason you can use a wrapper such as

```
data Some t where
    Some :: t a -> Some t
```

and you can derive e.g. an `Eq` instance for `Some ModelName` manually:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

instance Eq (Some ModelName) where
    Some UnitModel == Some UnitModel
        = True

    Some (CyclicModel n) == Some (CyclicModel n')
        = n == n'

    Some (Product m1 m2) == Some (Product m1' m2')
        = Some m1 == Some m1' && Some m2 == Some m2'

    Some (Power m1) == Some (Power m1')
        = Some m1 == Some m1'

    _ == _ = False
```

Comment: Did you just hacked into my Emacs coz I had the same answer ready :)

Comment: One of the approaches I tried was similar to this but didn't have the type constraints in the constructor types, so that clears up one issue for me -- thanks.  But one reason I went looking for other approaches was the feeling that a definition like this bakes in too much information about one of its particular uses:  I might also want to write code that works only with the names, where the extra type information would be superfluous, say an isomorphism test `ModelName -> ModelName -> Bool`.  Is there a way to keep the original ModelName definition for those purposes but still allow model_of?

Comment: data ErasedModel = forall t. ErasedModel (ModelName t) -- wouldn't recommend it though :-)

Comment: And BTW, what is the right way to derive Show and Eq for ModelName t?  That was a feature of my original ModelName but something that also gave me trouble when I tried converting it to a GADT.

Comment: I added some more information about deriving type-class instances.